# Calendar not displaying all stored dates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, calendar, datepicker

I am using an ASP calendar to show a list of dates, however the way the calendar overlaps and may show the last few dates of March, with the entire month of April, with the first few days of may(please see images below) is causing a problem.

I have set the 'startDate' and 'endDate' to be the start and end of that month. So if the user clicks 10th April, it will show all the stored dates btn 1st april to the 30th april. I need to change this to include the month b4 and the month after, SO any date in april will include all of March, April and May.
**'Green is the date selected by the user, red is todays date, and blue are the stored dates in the DB table.'**

[image]

[image]

```
DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(DiaryDate.Year, DiaryDate.Month, 1);
DateTime endOfMonth = startOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

The above code selects the first and last date of each month (of the chosen date)
I want to select the entire previous current and next month
not sure on the correct syntax. any help appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// First, get the dates a month before - and after - the specified date.
DateTime nextMonth = DiaryDate.AddMonths(1);
DateTime lastMonth = DiaryDate.AddMonths(-1);

// Get the last day of next month.
DateTime endOfNextMonth = new DateTime(nextMonth.Year, nextMonth.Month,
    DateTime.DaysInMonth(nextMonth.Year, nextMonth.Month));

// Get the first day of last month.
DateTime startOfLastMonth = new DateTime(lastMonth.Year, lastMonth.Month, 1);
```

Now you can simply use `endOfNextMonth` and `startOfLastMonth` as your "boundary" dates, as you are currently doing with `startOfMonth` and `endOfMonth`.